# ReferenceError in gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp, phpstorm, gulp-sass

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', done => {
    gulp.src('./css/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));

    done()
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', done => {
    gulp.watch('./css/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));

    done()
});

gulp.task('compressed-js', done => {
    gulp.src('js/src/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));

    done()
});

gulp.task('compressed-js:watch', done => {
    gulp.watch('./js/src/*.js', gulp.series('compressed-js'));

    done()
});
```

In the `phpstorm` getting this **error**: `"ReferenceError: sourcemaps is not defined"`

Comment: Let us know what's the error / exception / problem you are facing or what's `wrong` output you are getting.

Comment: Please edit your question, there are repetition in the sentences.

Comment: I can not remove the repetition, the site swears. As for the error:
"ReferenceError: sourcemaps is not defined"
phpstorm says it

Comment: ok. I will add it to the question

Comment: You got the right answer only because I edited https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54568157/revisions the question as well as the title. please keep in mind to provide description of your problem. Otherwise people will just downvote and you wont get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) is pretty self-explanatory: you're referring to the `sourcemaps` variable while it doesn't exist.

Normally, you would need to declare it at the top of your gulpfile, like so:

```js
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
```

However, Gulp 4 has [sourcemap functionality built-in](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#sourcemaps), so you can rewrite your `sass` task like this:

```js
gulp.task('sass', () =>
  gulp.src('./css/**/*.sass', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.', { sourcemaps: '.' }))
);
```

Note that I removed the `done` callback, which isn't needed if you just return the stream.

Note that you will run into the same problem when running the `compressed-js` task. You'll need to define `uglify` and `rename`:

```js
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

And make sure the packages you require are installed.

Comment: added all variables (gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-uglify.gulp-rename) + installed. Also added a new tast (sass)
Well, here's the trouble
1) sass (works)
2) sass (watch:) - no)

no errors, but no compilation

Comment: oo..thank you) I found my mistake, you need to register a folder there, I will go to solve the problem. Thank you for the advice, This is not Russia, where nobody will help you